# Simple variable assignment in Excel 2003 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA in Excel.  I'm setting up a simple macro

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
   Dim sheet
   sheet = Worksheets.Item(1)  ' This line has the error
End Sub
```

On the line with the error, I get "Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method"

I can use the Watch window to see that "Worksheets.Item(1)" is a valid object.  I've tried changing it to "Dim sheet As Worksheet" but same result.

Ok, so what am I missing?  Why does this error occur?

Thanks!

-Mike

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think the object it is talking about is "Worksheets", and it is trying to tell you that it does not support the "Item" property/method. Is this based on some sample code you found?

Comment: Nope, code I'm writing from scratch.  If I type in "Worksheets." I get the intellisense for "Item("

Comment: great question.  The reason you need `Set` is because `sheet` is an object and not a simple type (such as integer, string, etc.).  You can also reference worksheets by name, such as `Set sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `Set` statement (as you are assigning a reference):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
   Dim sheet As Worksheet
   Set sheet = Worksheets.Item(1) 

   '' ... Use sheet

   Set sheet = Nothing
End Sub
```